# Mosquitto maximum bridge persistence

Tags: persistence, mqtt, mosquitto

I need to bridge two mqtt broker. 
The first is mosquitto and it run locally.
The second is another mosquitto instance and run remotely.
I'm using the bridge functionality with persistence enabled to forward the messages from the first broker to the second one.
This is my conf:

```
# Bridge test
connection br-win-to-deb
bridge_insecure true
address 192.168.138.166:1883
cleansession false
clientid br-win-deb
start_type automatic

notifications false
try_private true

# Forward di tutti i messaggi con topic GATEWAY su topic AZURE
topic # out 2 GATEWAY/ AZURE/

persistence true
persistence_file Messages.db
persistence_location C:/temp/

max_queued_messages 36000000
autosave_interval 10

queue_qos0_messages true
```

Actually it works but when the file Messages.db reach approx 1Gb and the used ram reach approx 2gb mosquitto crash.
I run mosquitto in windows 7 x64.
The number of messages is something like 10000000 but i need at least 36000000.
Is it a problem of memory? Is there a limit?
Does exists a mqtt broker that support that huge msg quantity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a problem of Windows version.
On Debian the problem is the same.
The mosquitto version I'm using is v.1.4.8 on both the OS.